# std::shared_ptr constructed from this

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I want to add all objects of a class to a `std::map`. Since I don't want to copy objects, I try to get a workaround using smart pointers like this:

**Class.h**

```
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public:
    A();
    ~A();
    static std::map<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<A>> getObjects();
private:
    static uint32_t counter;
    uint32_t id;
    static std::map<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<A>> objects;
};
```

**Class.cpp**

```
A::A()
{
    id = counter++;
    std::shared_ptr<A> ptr = std::make_shared<A>();
    objects[id] = ptr->shared_from_this();
}

A::~A()
{
    objects.erase(id);
}

std::map<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<A>> A::getObjects()
{
    return objects;
}

uint32_t A::counter=0;

std::map<uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<A>> A::objects;
```

This compiles fine but when trying to use it like this

```
int main(){
    A a;
    A b;
    auto objects = A::getObjects();
}
```

i get

> Segmentation fault: 11`

If I try to change the constructor to

```
A::A()
{
    id = counter++;
    std::shared_ptr<A> ptr(this);
    objects[id] = ptr->shared_from_this();
}
```

i get

> pointer being freed was not allocated

I basically need to get a `std::shared_ptr<A>` constructed from `this` but can't manage to get it work.

Comment: It sounds like you might be violating [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this): *It is permitted to call `shared_from_this` only on a previously shared object, i.e. on an object managed by `std::shared_ptr`.*

Comment: If you want to do this, you have to make sure that you only allocate objects of type `A` as `shared_ptr`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code has a stack-overflow:

> ```
> A::A()
> {
>     id = counter++;
>     std::shared_ptr<A> ptr = std::make_shared<A>();
>     objects[id] = ptr->shared_from_this();
> }
> ```

You unconditionally construct `A` within `A`'s constructor.

What you then tried also doesn't work:

> ```
> A::A()
> {
>     id = counter++;
>     std::shared_ptr<A> ptr(this);
>     objects[id] = ptr->shared_from_this();
> }
> ```

`shared_from_this()` only works if this object's lifetime is being managed by a `std::shared_ptr`.

---

There are a couple options for what you could do. You *could* use a static factory function and not expose the constructor, but that's an unexpected design for your class.

What seems a clearer design to me is to do something similar to the Pimpl pattern. You can have `std::shared_ptr`s to the actual implementation of `A`, and wrap the functionality in an object that simply contains the `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get an owning shared pointer to an object not managed by a shared pointer.

Automatic storage objects lifetime may not have their lifetime managed by a shared pointer.

In general, your design cannot be done, as objects and object lifetime is controlled by the code creating the object, not the object itself.

Smart pImpl wrappers can make the guts of an object have a separate smart pointer determined lifetime.  But even there that shared pointer solution is illegal, as destroying the map can kill the last shared pointer, which then attempts to reenter the map code and erase it.  This is undefined behaviour.

A mixture of weak pointer map contents, pImpl based wrappers, smart deleters that deregister instances, and other work might work.  That is beyond the scope of a SO answer.

You have to learn about how to manage object lifetime, how weak ptrs work, alternative deleters, pImpl based value-types, and a myriad of other subjects to pull this off.   Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you need all instances of a class stored in a global map, you can try this: 1) hide all constructors; 2) only create new objects via a static ('factory') method. In your case, this method can return a `shared_ptr` (or, say, it can return a reference, the shared_ptr itself private to the global map; in this case you can even use unique_ptr).